# How to pass the object with performSelector:withObject:withObject:

Tags: objective-c, delegates, ipad, selector

I have a check where I see if the delegate responds to a callback, then I try to performSelector:withObject:withObject:

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:self.callback])
{
    [delegate performSelector:callback withObject:object withObject:error];
}
```

When this is executed, I end up in the callback method of

```
-(void)thisIsMyCallBack {
    //NSLog(@"object = ", object);
}
```

But I do not have access to the object.

I tried to create another method

```
-(void)thisIsMyCallBack:(NSObject *)object withObject:(NSObject *)error {
    //NSLog(@"object = ", object);
}
```

but this is not called, and the callback goes to the first one.

How do I access the objects that I want to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to set your callback property to:

```
@selector(thisIsMyCallBack:withObject:)
```

In Obj-C, the the bits that look like named parameters to a method are really part of the method's selector. `thisIsMyCallBack:withObject:` is not the same as `thisIsMyCallBack`.